# A lot of TDD questions in one day - Is this normal?

Tags: discussion

In the last hours a lot of TDD questions was asked - the most of them from new users. I do not know, but it is not something abnormal?

I am not against new questions or a lot of new questions in a short time. Each new good asked question is welcome on this site. The same applies for new users. But in this case I am not sure if this real users are.

What do you think?

This is my first post in the meta area. I hope it is the right place to ask questions like this and to tell the community my toughts.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like TXState homework questions based on users email addresses.

Comment: TXState? Did you mean that a university told their pupils to post questions on SQA.se?